# Get list of Java Files in Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there an easy way to get a list of Java files that have a specific Annotation within a Maven Plugin?  I want to run the plugin as part of deploy to call another service that notifies of all of the classes that have the specific annotation.

I have in the past done this at runtime using the Reflections library as below

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(PACKAGE);
Set<Class<?>> checks = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(FocusCheck.class);
```

I think it can be done by doing something like

```
 @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
MavenProject project;
```

then

```
List<String> compileSourceRoots = project.getCompileSourceRoots();
```

I would then need to recursively go down each folder in the list and find the java files and examine them.  I suspect that there is a better way to do this.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I would look at how other libraries do the same thing, for example check how Spring scans packages for certain annotations.

Comment: Do you have a link that would give me a starting point please?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some of the following `Spring` source code:

**NOTE:** method shrunk for readability

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider 
/**
 * Scan the class path for candidate components.
 * @param basePackage the package to check for annotated classes
 * @return a corresponding Set of autodetected bean definitions
 */
public Set<BeanDefinition> findCandidateComponents(String basePackage) {
    Set<BeanDefinition> candidates = new LinkedHashSet<BeanDefinition>();
    try {
        String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX +
                resolveBasePackage(basePackage) + "/" + this.resourcePattern;
        Resource[] resources = this.resourcePatternResolver.getResources(packageSearchPath);
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            // check its metadata to see if it's what you want
        }
    }
    return candidates;
}
```

---

`getResources()` eventually calls the following method to get the class resources from the classpath:

```
org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
/**
 * Find all class location resources with the given path via the ClassLoader.
 * Called by {@link #findAllClassPathResources(String)}.
 * @param path the absolute path within the classpath (never a leading slash)
 * @return a mutable Set of matching Resource instances
 * @since 4.1.1
 */
protected Set<Resource> doFindAllClassPathResources(String path) throws IOException {
    Set<Resource> result = new LinkedHashSet<Resource>(16);
    ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
    Enumeration<URL> resourceUrls = (cl != null ? cl.getResources(path) : ClassLoader.getSystemResources(path));
    while (resourceUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = resourceUrls.nextElement();
        result.add(convertClassLoaderURL(url));
    }
    if ("".equals(path)) {
        // The above result is likely to be incomplete, i.e. only containing file system references.
        // We need to have pointers to each of the jar files on the classpath as well...
        addAllClassLoaderJarRoots(cl, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So it seems like using the `ClassLoader` to get the class resources under a package then checking the metadata of those classes is an ok way to go.